# UIVisualEffectView bottom corner radius

Tags: swift2, mask, cornerradius, uivisualeffectview

I am trying to apply mask to `UIVisualEffectView` to make bottom corners rounded, but for some reason i have an error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" in here `".BottomRight | .BottomLeft"`

and the second problem is if i make only one rounded corner then `UIVisualEffectView` constraines goes wrong

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var visualEffect: UIVisualEffectView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
     super.awakeFromNib()

     let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
     rectShape.bounds = self.visualEffect.frame
     rectShape.position = self.visualEffect.center
     rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.visualEffect.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .BottomRight | .BottomLeft, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).CGPath
     self.visualEffect.layer.mask = rectShape
}
```

How it is possible to fix this issues?
Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes, first problem was because difference in Swift 1 and Swift 2. And second problem - i just use image that i draw in Sketch instead UIVisualEffect